# Can I recover an SVN repository by copying the server files?

Tags: svn

I'm trying to recover the data of an SVN repository of ours, that had not been backed up with canonical methods like `svnadmin dump`. (Yeah, I know.) I've already set up an identical SVN server, but I'm wondering if I could restore the repository just by copying the files from `/var/lib/svn/reponame` into the same folder of the new server.

Also, I'm recovering those files from the `lost+found` folder, so I don't have the actual name of the repository (in the example above, that would be `reponame`). Where is the repository name stored? Does it matter if I put the files of what was `reponame` into `/var/lib/svn/newname`?

Comment: What's the result of `svnadmin verify /var/lib/svn/reponame`?

Comment: I don't think that Subversion repositories have names... :-?

Comment: @bahrep Unfortunately, what I thought was the folder of my repository is actually something else. I got it from `lost+found`, the tree structure looked promising, but they're actually non-related files. However, for the sake of learning, what could I expect from `svnadmin verify`, and what could I do depending on its result?

Comment: @Simone http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svnadmin.c.verify.html